# Is it possible to attach value to form's action url through jQuery?

Tags: jquery

basically whenever the user clicks an anchor tag or submits a form, I need to ask the user for a "reason" via javascript prompt, and whatever text he inputs needs to be attached to the existing url parameters before sending.

so when anchor tag with `href='index.php?id=32'` is clicked, I want to visit the link `'index.php?id=32&reason="Some_reason"'`....similarly for forms in the submit event I want to override the action url with the reason before proceeding with submit.

I think I can do the anchor tag by grabbing attr('href'), encoding it and then using header location replace. But I have no idea about the form....

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a hidden field:

```
$("form").submit({
 var field = $("[name=reason]", this); // Check if the field already exists
 if (field.length == 0) { // If not generate one
   field = $("<input type='hidden' name='reason'>").appendTo($(this));
 }
 field.val(prompt("Reason?", field.val()));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
jQuery('#formId').attr('action', value);
```

Comment: Ok but how do I continue with the submission and make sure I am proceeding after the parameter modification?

Comment: call jQuery('#formId').submit();

Comment: Umm I believe I said I am gonna have to set the action from within the submit event of the form, and I don't think it would be wise to call the submit function from within the submit event.

Comment: This code is meant to be hooked to input onClick event, not submit

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#formId').attr('action', value);
```

Should do the trick, note however that if you want to POST your reason, you will need RoToRa's approach.

Finally, to submit your form after parameter modification, you could simply use

```
$('#formId').submit();
```